# Is there a way to put variable criteria within a join in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is this: I need to join two tables together, keeping all data from one table. It will be a one-to-many match. I need to set criteria within the one-to-many match. Example:

```
TableA                           TableB
Name    Date      Cat            Name    Date
AAA     1/1/17    Z11            AAA     1/2/17
AAA     1/4/17    Y22            AAA     1/6/17
AAA     1/7/17    X33            BBB     1/2/17
BBB     1/1/17    A44
BBB     1/3/17    B55
```

I need to join TableA to TableB, keeping all of the records from TableB, joining on the Name column. The "local record" I wish to join to in TableA is the smallest date that is still larger than the date in TableB. So the desired results would be:

```
Results
TableB.Name    TableB.Date    TableA.Cat
AAA            1/2/17         Y22
AAA            1/6/17         X33
BBB            1/2/17         B55
```

I know I want an outer join on the two names, but don't know how to work in the "local criteria" for lack of a better way to phrase it. Is this possible, and how is it done?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a subquery out of tableA for what you want and join on that.

The subquery excludes a.dates that are less than b.dates. With those that are left, grab the min.

Join all of that to the tableB

```
SELECT  b.name ,
        b.date ,
        a.cat
FROM    tableb b
        JOIN ( SELECT   a1.name ,
                        MIN(a1.date) AS date
               FROM     tableA a1
                        JOIN tableb b1 ON a1.name = b1.name
                                          AND a1.date > b1.date
             ) a ON a.date > b.date
                    AND a.name = b.name;
```

Comment: This doesn't work, for one thing the dates aren't *equal*

Comment: Ah, sorry, force of habit, I'll change the = to a >

Comment: Actually he wants the smallest date from A that is greater than B. I think your solution is in the right way, but your subquery will need to include tableB too.

Comment: @jfneis, you're right, that was a reading fail on my part. I've edit the answer appropriatly

Answer (score 1):

I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select b.*,
       (select a.cat
        from a
        where a.name = b.name and a.date > b.date
        order by a.date asc
        limit 1
       ) as cat
from b;
```